# SQL Sampling based on the whole population

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a population of records...let's say 10,000 athletes, grouped by sports, where (numbers below would be variable):

```
4,000 are from NBA
2,000 are from NHL
3,000 are from MLB 
1,000 are from NFL
```

How can I build a sample query that will sample 100 records based on the population, not fully random but pull out:

NBA/Whole Population=X
Select Top X * From MainTable Where league= 'NBA' (something like this)

40 names are from NBA
20 names are from NHL
30 names are from MLB
10 names are from NFL.

This is just a sample of the population, logic here is to calculate what the ratios are with regard to the whole population and then apply them to the sample size.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL random sample with groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235542/sql-random-sample-with-groups)

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: @PeterB - How did you assume it is `SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a count correlated subquery for a rank order that you then use as filtering criteria for sample ratio.

```
SELECT main.*
FROM 
   (SELECT *,
         (SELECT Count(*) FROM MainTable sub 
          WHERE sub.League = t.League AND sub.UniqueID <= t.UniqueID) As Rank
    FROM MainTable t) AS main

WHERE main.Rank <= CInt((SELECT Count(*) FROM MainTable sub
                         WHERE sub.League = main.League) / 
                         (SELECT Count(*) FROM MainTable) * 100)
ORDER BY main.League, main.Rank
```

To explain above query with nested subqueries and derived tables:

1. The derived table, *main*, is exact source *MainTable* with a new column called *Rank* that gives an ordinal count of records for each League. So for the first NBA record (not necessarily first row), it is tagged rank 1, next NBA record (which can appear anywhere like 89th row) is tagged 2, and so on for each League. And yes, *Rank* will go up to 4,000 if needed!
2. Once this *Rank* field is calculated giving ordinal 1, 2, 3, ... indicators for each League grouping, we then position this `SELECT` statement as a derived table in `FROM` clause in order to use *Rank* in `WHERE` filter for the sample ratio. We cannot calculate a column and filter in same `SELECT` call.
3. Sample ratio is the last two subqueries used for a quotient that calculates: (# of League records matching current row / total # of table records). This value is then multiplied by 100 per sample quota. `CInt` is used to return integer values of possible decimal ratios. Consider also `Round(..., 0)` which rounds instead of strips decimal points.

Comment: Parfait...is there a way to randomize the rank? It seems like it ranks the records the same way....what if I wanted to get different results every time I run this query?

Comment: Good question. Consider asking as a new one as the answer may involve application layer code (VBA, PHP, Python, Java, etc.) above database layer. SQL in the end is only a special-purpose, declarative language where columns/variables once declared are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Leagues(1 To 4) As String

Leagues(1) = "NHL"
Leagues(2) = "MLB"
Leagues(3) = "NFL"
Leagues(4) = "MLS"


Set db = CurrentDb

For x = 1 To 4

y = 0
sqql = "Select * from Maintable Where League = '" & leagues(x) & "'"

Set cf = db.OpenRecordset(sqql)

Set samp = db.OpenRecordset("RANDOMSAMPLE")






Do While y < (x * 1000) ' adjust as necessary just swagged in you wanted 1000 from league 1, 2000 league 2 etc

cf.MoveLast
cf.MoveFirst

i = Int((cf.RecordCount - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

cf.Move (i)

With samp

.AddNew

.fields("Yourfield here") = cf![your field ]

' repeat as nec

.Update

End With
y = y + 1
Loop


cf.Close
Next x

samp.Close
```